# Visual Studio 2013 SSDT-BI will not display .sql files In Default Editor Selector

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've just upgraded a 2008R2 Analysis Services project to VS2013 using SSDT-BI. I'm having problems opening any .sql files attached to the project. When opening using "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, Editor Selector(Default)" the files display as empty. Opening another file crashes VS 2013.

I can get the files to open using the JSON Editor but this is not ideal.

Anyone know whats going on?

T